# Better to use list of items or indexes in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am taking some Python classes and they have create a sub-list of items, which are rows from a dataset.
I am wondering **Why they don't suggest using a list of the indexes instead of list the whole data rows.**

For example
list_of_freeApps.append(row[x])

Seems like saving index only:
list_of_freeApps.append(x)
would be more efficient space-wise, but maybe Python interpreter does something so no need to worry about this,

OR This is a beginner class and when using Python Panda dataframes it will be taken care of?

So could someone please comment on this Python beginner question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A list containing the subsequence actually uses *less* additional space than a list of the subsequence's indices. The reason for this is that lists only contain references to their members; when you create a new list containing some of the old list's elements, the new list only holds references to those members. Those members already exist, no copies of them are made, so the only memory used is to hold the new references to them in the new list.

A list of indices uses a bit more memory because it holds references to integer objects, which have to be created and take up memory, instead of references to some already-existing objects.

The rather helpful [Python Tutor tool](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B'foo',%20'bar',%20'baz'%5D%0A%0Asub_a%20%3D%20a%5B1%3A%5D%0A%0Asub_indices%20%3D%20%5B1,%202%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=true&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) can show a visualisation of this in memory, which might help you to understand my explanation. Click the "Next" button to see which objects are created in memory as the code runs.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly the kind of info I was looking for. And for introducing me to Python Tutor tool.